# Orchard - How to display custom Term fields in a taxonomy field?

Tags: orchardcms

I've got a contentType (product) that has a taxonomy field (features).  The taxonomy term (product feature term) has been customized to include an image field and a description field.

I'd like for the product detail view to display the image from the term along with the name, but I can't find the property to access it.

I've created the following:

### Taxonomy

1. ProductFeature Taxonomony

   - Vocabulary: Feat1, Feat2, Feat3

### ContentTypes

2. Product

   - Fields: Features(Taxonomy)
3. Product Features Term

   - Fields: Description(Html), Image(Image)

### Views

Fields.Contrib.TaxonomyField-Features.cshtml

```
<!-- Old Code -->
@if (Model.Terms.Count > 0) {
<p class="taxonomy-field">
    <span class="name">@name.CamelFriendly():</span> 
    @(new HtmlString( string.Join(", ", terms.Select(t => Html.ItemDisplayLink(Html.Encode(t.Name), t.ContentItem ).ToString()).ToArray()) ))
</p>
}

<!-- New Code -->
@if (Model.Terms.Count > 0)
{
    <div>
        @foreach (var myTerm in Model.Terms)
        {   
            @Display(???)
        }
    </div>
}
```

What do replace the question marks with?  I'd thought it'd be myTerm.Image but that field doesn't exist on the dynamic object.

I've attached an image of the designer viewer.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Sebastien helped me figure out over on http://orchardtaxonomies.codeplex.com/discussions/263844

Below is what ended up working.

(The key bit being: **contentField = myTerm.ContentItem.Features.TermImage;**)

```
@foreach (var myTerm in Model.Terms)
{
    var contentField = myTerm.ContentItem.Features.TermImage;
    if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(contentField.FileName)) {
        <p class="image-field">
           <img src="@Url.Content(contentField.FileName)" alt="@contentField.AlternateText" width="@contentField.Width" height="@contentField.Height"/>
        </p>
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you wanted to use the current dev branch on the module, you could access the TermsPart of the content items, which leads you to all currently applied terms.

If you are using version 0.9 of the module, then you can dynamically have access to the fields by getting a reference to your Content Item, then do contentItem.PARTNAME.FIELDNAME. In the case of a type named Product, and a field name Feature it would be contentItem.Product.Feature. Then if this term has a property named Image, it will be termContentItem.ProductTerm.Image.

I would need more information to give you the exact syntax, like the type of field, exact name of content types. Or you can post the question on the module's codeplex project discussion forum.

Comment: I posted this over on modules codeplex discussions.  http://orchardtaxonomies.codeplex.com/discussions/263844